# Soap request from php cleint to the Android Server..?

Tags: php, android, soap

I have tried to set up a Soap connection between a Php client and making the Android app as a server. I tried it by getting the Android device Ip address and setting a request in php client..?  I was not successful in doing so. Need some help with this.?

Comment: i m still unclear with ur question , can u paste some code

Comment: I guess that android is always going to have  the soap client and your php script will have the server, isn't true?

Comment: Edit :  Php has separate client and also server code. I am using nusoap. So cant we make android the similar way so that we can able to access android server from the php client code through network by getting the android device Ip or some other way.?